# Are questions about receiving social security benefits while abroad on topic?

Tags: discussion

I have a question I would like to ask regarding eligibility of receiving social security as a citizen of the USA while abroad in Sweden for a given period of time. Are such questions on topic for the Travel Stack Exchange?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I have a question I would like to ask regarding eligibility of receiving social security as a citizen of the USA while abroad in Sweden for a given period of time.

That'd be on-topic on https://money.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I think https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/ is even better.

Answer (score 4):

I think not, as you will have to be in Sweden for more than a holiday for it to be relevant.

I expect our sister site Expatriates Stack Exchange might work.

Comment: Is that true even if it's a temporary stay that lasts for an extended period (around 80 days)?

Answer (score 3):

That's more of a lengthy stay and therefore off-topic.

I'd try [Expatriates SE.](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/)